# Move controls with the mouse in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, events, mouse

I want to build a simple forms designer in Cocoa and need to move controls around on a form using the mouse (click, hold, move around, release).

Do I need to inherit new classes from all control classes to intercept those events ? Is there a way to implement it generically for any control?

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to have a single large custom view that fills all the space the controls will be in. Implement the necessary methods to implement mouse events in this view, doing hit detection on the control views and moving them around. This approach requires only 1 custom subclass of NSView, and you can use any views or controls you want to move around without subclassing them.

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom view to contain the controls. Override `-hitTest:` to ignore the controls and return `self` instead. Then when you receive mouse events, figure out which control they apply to and move as appropriate.